# Should my question be deleted if my answer is RTFM

Tags: discussion

I had asked a question regarding writing an R package.  ([Can't fix warning when redefining log as a generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986174/cant-fix-warning-when-redefining-log-as-a-generic))

As it turns out, my solution was to read the manual and learn the the method I was trying to make generic is already a generic.  Is this a situation where I ought to answer the question, or would it be better to delete the question entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"RTFM" is not the answer. "RTFM" is how you *found* the answer!

Answer your question with a summary of what you found in the manual that helped you solve your problem, with a link to the part of the manual where you found it. In this case, this might be something along the lines of:

> [Chapter 123 of the manual](https://example.com) explains that this error means [or: can mean?] that the method is already a generic. You can't make it generic again.

Comment: Just duplicating the manual isn't useful at all, given that the answer is already in the manual.

Comment: @Servy The question seems to be based around an unclear error message. Unless the manual addresses that error message very specifically, I don't think it makes sense to say "the answer is in the manual" -- even if the OP managed to find some information in the manual that helped them, documenting the link between that error message and the documentation is useful.

Comment: The *premise* of the question was that just knowing that the answer was in the manual was enough.  If you're saying that it doesn't make sense to say, "the answer was in the manual" then you're not talking about the situation the OP specifically asked about.

Answer (score 4):

If the manual provides a quality answer to the question, and you don't have anything meaningful to add beyond what's there, then by all means, delete the question, as it's not adding any value to duplicate the same information.

If you can provide an answer that's actually adding value beyond what's in the manual, such that the answer to the SO question is actually a better answer than what's in the manual, then by all means, post such an answer.